# Problem to install angular project in aws

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2

I am tring to execute npm install in my aws,
I use
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --public  myip.amazonaws.com

And I have the following error:

```
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(project).
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(project).
    at MergeMapSubscriber._registry.compile.pipe.operators_1.concatMap.validatorResult [as project] (/home/ec2-user/angular/tesis/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace.js:210:42)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/home/ec2-user/angular/tesis/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:65:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/home/ec2-user/angular/tesis/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:55:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/home/ec2-user/angular/tesis/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/home/ec2-user/angular/tesis/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:84:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (/home/ec2-user/angular/tesis/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/InnerSubscriber.js:25:21)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/home/ec2-user/angular/tesis/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (/home/ec2-user/angular/tesis/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/map.js:52:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/home/ec2-user/angular/tesis/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:64:18)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/home/ec2-user/angular/tesis/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:77:26)
```

I dont know was is the problem

```
  My actual versions are:
    Package                      Version
    ------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.8.1
@angular-devkit/core         0.8.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.1
@angular/cdk                 6.2.1
@angular/cli                 6.2.1
@angular/material            6.2.1
@schematics/angular          0.8.1
@schematics/update           0.8.1
rxjs                         6.3.2
typescript                   2.9.2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng build --prod command to build your application which creates the dist folder in your local machine with production evnvironment and you can move the dist folder directly to server root path

Your server configuration document root path will be like this /var/www/html/dist

Make sure to add .htcaccess for reload if you using apache server